# Get ItemChild properties using Powershell Script SharePoint 2013 document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, document-library

We have a document library which contains multiple document set we have below requirements :

1. Get all document set properties like Name, Created Date, Modified date.
2. Get all ItemChild (document present inside the document set) properties Name, Created Date, Modified date.

We are able to get document set properties but unable to get ItemChild properties, any lead much appreciated, Please find my below code.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

$web = Get-SPWeb "Site URL"

$list = $web.Lists["ENERGY"]


foreach ($listItem in $list.Items)
{
$CabinetName = $listItem['Name']
$CabinetCreateDate = $listItem['Created']
$CabinetModifiedDate = $listItem['Modified']
$CabinetChildItemCount = $listItem['ItemChildCount']

   Write-Host "    Cabinet Name: " $listItem.Name "  Modified: " $CabinetModifiedDate "Cabinet ChildItem Count" $CabinetChildItemCount "Created Date:" $CabinetCreateDate

}
$web.Dispose ()
```

Comment: `$folders = $list.RootFolder.Subfolders

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{

$CabinetName = $folder.Name
$CabinetItemCount = $folder.ItemCount

$folderItems = $folder.Item

Write-Host "Cabinet Name:" $CabinetName "Cabinet Item count:" $CabinetItemCount 

}`

Comment: Tried with this... It's working but not getting child item properties

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a script and tested it. Please make changes in case you don't want anything. it's giving correct output.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

# Enter site URL for which reports needs to be generated 
$web = Get-SPWeb " "

#Enter List/Document Library name
$list = $web.Lists["UW_ENERGY"]

#Enter local machine path where you want generate report
$path ="C:\Users\Desktop\Sachin\May2020\"


$resultantfile = $path +"CompleteReport.csv"

Add-Content -Path $resultantfile -Value "Cabinet URL|CabinetFileName|CreatedDate|ModifiedDate|Document Count|Type"

# Variable used for split the URL
$separator = "/"

foreach($item in $list.items)
{

            $ItemURL = $item.Url
            $ItemName = $item.Name
            $ItemCreatedDate = $item['Created'] 
            $ItemModifiedDate = $item['Modified']

            $DocuemntSet = $ItemURL.split($separator)

            if($DocuemntSet[2] -eq $ItemName )

            {
             $ItemChildCount = $item['ItemChildCount']
             $Doctype = "Cabinet"
            }
            else
            {
            $Doctype = "Child Item"
            $ItemChildCount = " "
            }

             write-host "Item URL:" $ItemURL "Item Name:" $ItemName "Item Create Date:"$ItemCreatedDate "Item Modified Date:"$ItemModifiedDate "Item Child Count:"$ItemChildCount "Type:"$Doctype

             $content = $ItemURL+"|"+$ItemName+"|" +$ItemCreatedDate+"|"+$ItemModifiedDate+"|" +$ItemChildCount +"|" +$Doctype +"|"                      
             Add-Content -Path $resultantfile -Value $content

 }

$web.Dispose()
```